# Android repo with "winsymlinks:nativestrict" in Cygwin

Tags: git, cygwin, symlink, repo

I'm using `cygwin` built-in git and python to for Android repo tool.

If I set `CYGWIN=winsymlinks`, everything works fine.

If I set `CYGWIN=winsymlinks:nativestrict` to tell cygwin to make windows native symlinks and run cygwin as Administrator, in a repo init procedure, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/cygdrive/d/repo/test/.repo/repo/main.py", line 506, in <module>
  _Main(sys.argv[1:])
File "/cygdrive/d/repo/test/.repo/repo/main.py", line 482, in _Main
  result = repo._Run(argv) or 0
File "/cygdrive/d/repo/test/.repo/repo/main.py", line 161, in _Run
  result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
File "/cygdrive/d/repo/test/.repo/repo/subcmds/init.py", line 390, in Execute
  self._SyncManifest(opt)
File "/cygdrive/d/repo/test/.repo/repo/subcmds/init.py", line 239, in _SyncManifest
  m.Sync_LocalHalf(syncbuf)
File "/cygdrive/d/repo/test/.repo/repo/project.py", line 1196, in Sync_LocalHalf
  self._InitWorkTree()
File "/cygdrive/d/repo/test/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2293, in _InitWorkTree
  copy_all=False)
File "/cygdrive/d/repo/test/.repo/repo/project.py", line 2276, in _ReferenceGitDir
  os.symlink(os.path.relpath(src, os.path.dirname(dst)), dst)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior and follows from incompatibilities between NTFS symlink and POSIX symlink models. From Cygwin help on [CYGWIN environment variable](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-cygwinenv.html):

> The difference between `winsymlinks:native` and `winsymlinks:nativestrict` is this: If the filesystem supports native symlinks and Cygwin fails to create a native symlink for some reason, it will fall back to creating Cygwin default symlinks with `winsymlinks:native`, while with `winsymlinks:nativestrict` the `symlink(2)` system call will immediately fail.

By the way, you're saying you're using `CYGWIN=winsymlinks`, but I don't see this exact option on the help page, so we can only guess to which variant (`:lnk`, `:native`, `:nativestrict`, or something else entirely) this corresponds.

Comment: If I use `ln -s source target` dirctly in Cygwin console with `winsymlinks:nativestrict`, that works. Only repo has the problem.  I think `winsymlinks` defaults to `winsymlinks:lnk`. If I use `dir` in dos console, I can see the Cygwin symlink with a `.lnk` suffix.

Comment: @Yorkwar, I assume the problem is that the symlinks are targeting files that don't exist yet. Try `ln -s non-existent-file other-file` -- that should show the difference.

Comment: I tried `ln -s srcsss tgtttt`. It complains `ln: failed to create symbolic link 'tgtttt': No such file or directory`. So, it seems that python cannot find the source. However, `winsymlinks:lnk` works.

Comment: Yes. The trick is that on Linux, it's normal to create symlinks to non-existent files. Cygwin normally allows for this behaviour, but it can't if you enforce the `nativestrict` setting.